# Cannot visualize anything on pygame, problem with the p.draw

Tags: python, pygame, pycharm

Good morning guys, I have a problem with my code, I'm trying to draw a chessboard on pygame but I get this error and I don't know really how to solve it

```
pygame 2.1.2 (SDL 2.0.16, Python 3.10.4)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
Fatal Python error: pygame_parachute: (pygame parachute) Segmentation Fault
Python runtime state: initialized

Current thread 0x00007f77e3750000 (most recent call first):
  File "/home/claudiosavelli/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1/main.py", line 34 in drawBoard
  File "/home/claudiosavelli/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1/main.py", line 25 in main
  File "/home/claudiosavelli/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1/main.py", line 37 in 

Extension modules: pygame.base, pygame.constants, pygame.rect, pygame.rwobject, pygame.surflock, pygame.color, pygame.bufferproxy, pygame.math, pygame.surface, pygame.display, pygame.draw, pygame.event, pygame.imageext, pygame.image, pygame.joystick, pygame.key, pygame.mouse, pygame.time, pygame.mask, pygame.pixelcopy, pygame.transform, pygame.font, pygame.mixer_music, pygame.mixer, pygame.scrap, pygame._freetype (total: 26)

Process finished with exit code 134 (interrupted by signal 6: SIGABRT)
```

This is my actual code, which is very simple so I don't know what the problem is:

```
    import pygame as p

WIDTH = 1080
HEIGHT = 720
BOARD_WIDTH = 448  # 64*7
BOARD_HEIGHT = 576  # 64*9
DIMENSION_ROW = 9
DIMENSION_COL = 7
SQUARE_SIZE = 64
MAX_FPS = 28
IMAGES = {}

MOVE_LOG_PANEL_WIDTH = 0

def main():
        p.init()
        screen = p.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
        screen.fill(p.Color("purple"))
        running = True

        while (running):
            for e in p.event.get():
                if e.type == p.quit():
                    running = False
            drawBoard(screen)

        return

def drawBoard(screen):
    colors = [p.Color("white"), p.Color("gray")]
    for r in range(DIMENSION_ROW):
        for c in range(DIMENSION_COL):
            color = colors[((r + c) % 2)]
            p.draw.rect(screen, color, p.Rect(c * SQUARE_SIZE, r * SQUARE_SIZE, SQUARE_SIZE, SQUARE_SIZE))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

The event type is `pygame.QUIT` and not `pygame.quit()`. By testing if the event is equal to `pygame.quit()` in your `if` in your event loop, in fact you called `pygame.quit()` and destroyed all the pygame context. Replace this and it will work.

By the way, don't forget to call `pygame.display.update()` after drawing your rectangles if you want your changes to appear on the screen.

Comment: Just did these change, the only problem is that now if I try to launch the game it stops responding and doesn't visualise the chessboard: https://ibb.co/gMRdJcM

Comment: I think it's something leads to the fact that it waits for doing an action when I want to select it and for this reason windows think that the application is not working

Comment: Did you add the `pygame.display.update()` ?

Comment: yes! And it solved everything, thanks to you all for the support!

Comment: No problem ! 
I really don't understand why it was marked as duplicate, as it is clearly not the same question..